# Compass fallback for IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, cross-browser, sass, compass-sass

I'm currently trying to integrate compass to my Rails project. Everything worked fine until I try on an old firefox version (3.0.18) and on a not so old version of IE (8).

For example, my header has a linear-gradient :

```
  +background-image(linear-gradient(#8fcbef, #cee8ff))
```

and it worked fine. But there is no automatic fallback for old browsers. Something like background-color: #8fcbef...

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few options here:

- specify the fallbacks for every single bit of css3 yourself, and start using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to ensure that they are only read when CSS3 is not interpreted
- try using [bourbon](http://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon) as it does provide fallbacks when you use CSS3

If you want to stick with compass, then give [html5-rails](https://github.com/sporkd/html5-rails) a try, as it embeds modernizr into your app so that you can selectively provide fallbacks only when they are needed

ps an example of a **modernizd** fallback would be:

```
// this rule is only applied if the browser is incapable of rendering css3-style gradients 
.no-cssgradients
  #header
    background-color: #8fcbef

// this rule is applied when css3 gradients are interpreted 
#header    
  +background-image(linear-gradient(#8fcbef, #cee8ff))
```

Comment: Bourbon is perfect for what I want. Thanks!